# Using different versions of the same library in a single script

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, package

I have a script where I use sklearn, version '0.24.0', and a library called autoimpute, that is built on top of sklearn's earlier version 0.22.1. The issue is that this earlier version of sklearn lacks certain features I need, such as mean_absolute_percentage_error metric built-in and some tweaks for handling categorical variables. Is there a way I can utilize both the latest sklearn and use autoimpute for the same script?

Comment: I can think of an ugly hack that would achieve something like that. However, I think it'd be a very bad idea. `autoimpute` depends on `scikit-learn>=0.20.2`, and a fresh install of `autoimpute` will install `scikit-learn 1.0.2` on Ubuntu 20.04, so it doesn't seem like it's `autoimpute` that's holding back the version here.

Comment: In my case on mac it is: ```Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in ./virt_env/virt2/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from autoimpute) (0.22.1)```

Comment: Since you already had it installed and the requirements are met, pip won't upgrade it. You can upgrade it manually, though

Comment: that will break a bunch of other dependent libraries that use earlier versions of sklearn. And the question relates to cases like mine in general, if there is a tool or workaround in these situations

Comment: Using an earlier version and depending on an earlier version are different things, so it depends on whether these other packages require the dependency be below a certain version or not. As it is now, it seems a bit unclear whether you have an unresolvable package conflict or your current venv is just in an undesirable state.